# JPA query, SQRT function not working in ORDER BY clause

Tags: java, eclipselink, jpql, jpa-2.0

I have following JPA query

```
SELECT p FROM Entity p WHERE p.type = (:type1) AND SQRT((( (:constlong)*(p.longitude - (:long)))*((:constlong)*(p.longitude - (:long)))) + (((:constlat) * (p.latitude - (:lat)))*((:constlat)*(p.latitude - (:lat))))) <= :rad ORDER BY SQRT((( (:constlong)*(p.longitude - (:long)))*((:constlong)*(p.longitude - (:long)))) + (((:constlat) * (p.latitude - (:lat)))*((:constlat)*(p.latitude - (:lat))))) ASC
```

This query was working fine with eclipselink 2.6.9 . After Updating to version 2.7.9, it stops working. When I remove the `ORDER BY` clause it works again.
I need to sort my entities by distance which is calculated in the `SQRT` expression.

Can somebody help with this?

**EDIT**

Here is the error:

```
18:08:58,197 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Query error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
18:08:58,197 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT p FROM Entity p WHERE p.type = (:type1) AND SQRT((( (:constlong)*(p.longitude - (:long)))*((:constlong)*(p.longitude - (:long)))) + (((:constlat) * (p.latitude - (:lat)))*((:constlat)*(p.latitude - (:lat))))) <= :rad ORDER BY SQRT((( (:constlong)*(p.longitude - (:long)))*((:constlong)*(p.longitude - (:long)))) + (((:constlat) * (p.latitude - (:lat)))*((:constlat)*(p.latitude - (:lat))))) ASC]. 
18:08:58,197 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) [553, 553] The right parenthesis is missing from the SQRT expression.
18:08:58,197 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) [635, 640] The query contains a malformed ending.
```

Here is the generated sql in eclipselink version 2.6.4

```
SELECT entityid, latitude, longitude FROM public.entity WHERE (((type = ?) OR (type = ?)) AND (SQRT((((? * (longitude - ?)) * (? * (longitude - ?))) + ((? * (latitude - ?)) * (? * (latitude - ?))))) <= ?)) ORDER BY SQRT((((? * (longitude - ?)) * (? * (longitude - ?))) + ((? * (latitude - ?)) * (? * (latitude - ?))))) ASC
```

And in version 2.7.7. without `order by`

```
SELECT entityid, latitude, longitude FROM public.entity WHERE (((type = ?) OR (type = ?)) AND (SQRT((((? * (longitude - ?)) * (? * (longitude - ?))) + ((? * (latitude - ?)) * (? * (latitude - ?))))) <= ?))
```

**2. EDIT**

I did some further digging. The query above is also not working with eclipselink version 2.6.9. But it's definitely working with version 2.6.4.
Something has changed between this 2 versions.

Comment: can you define working and not working - is there an error, or is it just not returning results? Can you show the SQL if it is the later case and compare what is generated using EL 2.6.9 and EL 2.7.9?

Comment: I pasted the error trace.

Comment: There is 100% no unbalanced parenthesis in the query. Cause the same query is working fine in older eclipselink version.

Comment: I just pasted the generated SQL.

Comment: ...fascinating! ..but with a [simple test like this](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/eclipselink/pull/575/files#diff-8dfd90225b502708f4e9a97ea5716e76960332ec3781f47c651a3766756a715a) (v.2.7.9 and your query), I could reproduce "2 grammar problems"! ..unfortunately i also reproduced it with 2.6.9 (and same query)!

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea what you mean. How is this related to Turkish locale? I'm not using turkish locale.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to switch to nativeQuery.
The query looks like following:

```
getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM entity p WHERE (p.type = ?) AND SQRT( (( 71.5*(p.longitude - ?))*( 71.5*(p.longitude - ?))) + (( 111.3 * (p.latitude - ?))*( 111.3*(p.latitude - ?)))) <= 15.0 ORDER BY SQRT( (( 71.5*(p.longitude - ?))*( 71.5*(p.longitude - ?))) + (( 111.3 * (p.latitude - ?))*( 111.3*(p.latitude - ?)))) ASC", Entity.class);
```